# Add fadein and fadeout to css and java slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I found and slide show using java and css only.
I need this because I also use background blend mode in my css script and that is not working on img src.

here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdUBZ/749/

also here:

```
    function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }

    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(6000, 10); //milliseconds, frames
```

And this is the css code:

```
#b1 { background: hsl(10, 50%, 50%); }
#b2 { background: hsl(30, 50%, 50%); }
#b3 { background: hsl(60, 50%, 50%); }
#b4 { background: hsl(90, 50%, 50%); }
#b5 { background: hsl(120, 50%, 50%); }
#b6 { background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%); }
#b7 { background: hsl(180, 50%, 50%); }
#b8 { background: hsl(210, 50%, 50%); }
#b9 { background: hsl(240, 50%, 50%); }
#b10 { background: hsl(270, 50%, 50%); }
```

Is there a way to add fadein and fadeout effect?
Also I noticed you can change the time in milliseconds.
The first Milliseconds there is no image loaded after the the milliseconds will end for the forst time than the first image will load. Is there a way to come up with the first image instantly

Kind regards,
Justin

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io

Comment: That's a very very bad implementation you got there BTW

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
body {
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Then the colors will fade into each other. If you use images, then they will fade in-out

Comment: I just added body {
    transition-duration: 1s;
} to the Java code. Then nothing happens?

Comment: @Justin Ok, it seems like you didn't understand it, this is **JavaScript** and **java =/= JavaScript**. You need to add that part to the **CSS**. Please learn this stuff before trying to use it.

Comment: Oke just got it to work THNX! Do you also know a whey how to start with a start image, not just a blank screen for the foor 6 seconds?